# Values change unexpectedly after function is called

Tags: python

can you lease tell me why `S[f'{colors[0]}']` is changing after calling this function, and how to fix it.

```
S = {"1": list(range(0,5)), "2": list(range(20,25)), "3": list(range(10,15))}
colors = [1, 2 ,3]

def count_bycolor(colors):
    countries_bycolor = S[f'{colors[0]}']
    for i in range(1, len(colors)):
        countries_bycolor.extend(S[f'{colors[i]}'])
    return countries_bycolor

count_bycolor(colors)
len(S[f'{colors[0]}'])
count_bycolor(colors)
len(S[f'{colors[0]}'])
```

Thank for your help, and happy holidays!

Comment: It is changing because you change it in the line `countries_bycolor.extend(S[f'{colors[i]}'])`. In order to help you, you will have to give more details on what you are trying to achieve here. What is your expected behaviour?

Comment: `countries_bycolor` is literally the list in `S` after `countries_bycolor = S[f'{colors[0]}']`; it's not a copy. If you want it to change independently, you need to [make a copy of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).

Comment: Clear, thanks and happy holidays.

Answer (score 2):

You are performing operations on a list in a dict. Both of these are mutable objects and due to python being [<s>passed by reference</s> pass-by-object-reference](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) that has this consequence of changing your "original" object (it's the same object).

This means that you need to [make copies](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/copy.html) of those objects if you want to operate on them without changing the original.

Based on your question it could be as simple as one line change:

```
import copy

def count_bycolor(colors):
    countries_bycolor = copy.copy(S[f'{colors[0]}'])
    for i in range(1, len(colors)):
        countries_bycolor.extend(S[f'{colors[i]}'])
    return countries_bycolor

count_bycolor(colors)

>>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

S

>>> {'1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], '2': [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], '3': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}
```

Comment: you can just use the `.copy` method available on both `list` and `dict` objects

Comment: True. This wasn't tagged as `3.x` though (yes I know we should all be on that since you've got about a week of `2.7` support left) and I believe that's a newer option.

Comment: Yes,  but for the generic python tag it is generally assumed to be Python 3. Also, it would explain the `list(range(...))` in the OPs code.

Comment: Very true, but it's a Friday afternoon so thinking ability is... :)